# Which corner case unit test would this fail?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I tried the [Fish problem on Codility](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/) and I secured 75% marks for correctness because the results reported that my code failed one simple test case. The results do not report what input was provided for the test case.

Could you please help me find out what is wrong with my code and what corner case it would fail?

```
using System;

public class Solution
{
    // Time complexity: O(N)
    // Space complexity: O(N)
    public int solution(int[] sizes, int[] direction)
    {
        if (sizes == null || direction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var sizesLen = sizes.Length;
        var directionLen = direction.Length;

        if (sizesLen != direction.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var len = sizesLen;

        if (len <= 1) return len;

        var survivors = new Fish[len];
        survivors[0] = new Fish(sizes[0], direction[0]);
        var curr = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            var fish = new Fish(sizes[i], direction[i]);

            if (survivors[curr].Direction == 1 && fish.Direction == 0)
            {
                if (fish.Size < survivors[curr].Size) continue;

                while(curr >= 0 && 
                    fish.Size > survivors[curr].Size && 
                    survivors[curr].Direction == 1)
                {
                    curr--;
                }
            }

            survivors[++curr] = fish;
        }

        return ++curr;
    }
}

public class Fish
{
    public Fish(int size, int direction)
    {
        Size = size;
        Direction = direction;
    }

    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it a time limit exceeded error or wrong answer error??

Comment: suppose A = [ 99, 98, 92, 91, 93 ], and B = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]. Your code gives answer as 3. Expected answer = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your code, your Solution is `O(M*N)`. As stated in the problem link, the code should run in linear time. Hence, I will not correct your solution as it will eventually fail on bigger test cases. I will provide you a linear algorithm that you can easily implement.

Keep a Stack `S`, empty initially.

Iterate over the array `A`, `i` from `0` to `n-1`

When you encounter an element, say `A[i]`, do the following

- If the stack `S` is empty, then push both (`A[i], B[i]`) as a pair
- Else, extract the top pair from the stack `S` and compare the value of `B[top]` and `B[i]`.

  *While* `B[top]` is `1` and `B[i]` is `0`, then one of the fishes will eat the other one. So pop from stack S, the top element. Now, compare which fish is bigger with values `A[top]` and `A[i]`. Whichever is bigger, that fish stays alive. Push that pair in the stack `S`, that corresponds to the fish that stays alive. Continue the *while* loop till the condition fails
  If `B[top]` is not `1` and `B[i]` is not `0`, then simply push the new pair (`A[i],B[i]`)

The size of the stack `S` at the end, is your answer.

Note: You might not be passing that test case, for which your solution times out. For example, for N=100000, your solution will time out.

In my solution, the worst case time complexity is `O(N+N)` = `O(2N)` = `O(N)`. `N` times because of the iteration over array `A` and another `N` times worst case, due to the Stack if it keeps shrinking, for the *while* condition holds `true`.

Hope it helps!!!

**Edit:** suppose A = [ 99, 98, 92, 91, 93 ], and B = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]. Your code gives answer as 3. Expected answer = 2

**Edit-2:** This is your modified code that will pass every test case

```
public int solution(int[] sizes, int[] direction)
    {
        if (sizes == null || direction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var sizesLen = sizes.Length;
        var directionLen = direction.Length;

        if (sizesLen != direction.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var len = sizesLen;

        if (len <= 1) return len;

        var survivors = new Fish[len];
        survivors[0] = new Fish(sizes[0], direction[0]);
        var curr = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            var fish = new Fish(sizes[i], direction[i]);

            if (survivors[curr].Direction == 1 && fish.Direction == 0)
            {
                if (fish.Size < survivors[curr].Size) continue;

                while(curr >= 0 && 
                    fish.Size > survivors[curr].Size && 
                    survivors[curr].Direction == 1)
                {
                    curr--;
                }

                if (curr >= 0)
                {
                    if (fish.Size < survivors[curr].Size && 
                         survivors[curr].Direction == 1) 
                               continue;
                }
            }

            survivors[++curr] = fish;
        }

        return ++curr;
    }

}

public class Fish
{
    public Fish(int size, int direction)
    {
        Size = size;
        Direction = direction;
    }

    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Water Cooler v2: Please have a look at your modified code. Does it work now?

Comment: Thank you so very much for taking all the trouble. While my algorithm wasn't very different from what you describe, your research and more specifically your modified version of my code put the finger on the problem. I wasn't checking if the present fish going upstream would get eaten up by the ones coming downstream that were earlier survivors. I wasn't worried so much about performance but for correctness. Thank you once more for the painstaking research and very helpful reply. I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: I edited your version of my modified code further to include an `if` condition such that `if (curr >= 0) { if (fish.Size < survivors[curr].Size && survivors[curr].Direction == 1) continue; }` because if the `survivors` stack already had been emptied, the statement would yield an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. For example, try running the code without the `if` statement with the sample input `A = new [] { 91, 92 }` and `B = new [] { 1, 0 }`.

Comment: Your Welcome... Actually your code is also `O(N)` contrary to the fact that you have mentioned it as `O(N*M)`. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you for the correction on this. I have edited the comment in the code in the original question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intention here is to use Stack or Queue. Here is a solution with two Stack.

```
  public static int Fish(int[] A, int[] B)
        {
            var downStreamFish = new Stack<int>(B.Length);
            var upStreamFish = new Stack<int>(B.Length);
            var result = B.Length;
            for (var i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
            {
                // push the fish into up/down stream stack.
                if (B[i] == 1)
                    downStreamFish.Push(i);
                else
                    upStreamFish.Push(i);

                // check to see whether it's possible to eat a fish
                while (downStreamFish.Count > 0 && upStreamFish.Count > 0)
                {
                    var dfIndex = downStreamFish.Peek();
                    var ufIndex = upStreamFish.Peek();
                    //NOTE:downstream fish index must be less than upstream fish index in order for 'eat' to happen
                    if (dfIndex < ufIndex) 
                    {
                        if (A[dfIndex] > A[ufIndex])
                            upStreamFish.Pop();
                        else
                            downStreamFish.Pop();

                        result--; // one fish is eatten
                    }
                    else
                        break; // eat condition is not met 
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```